# What am I missing in following Code for Javascript Clone?

Tags: javascript, html, clone

My Project is about client side cloning but facing problems as I am new to this.
Following is my sample code , displaying fields but not functioning as required, please anyone let me know what I am missing here....

Sample taken from following link:
https://jsfiddle.net/kamalswami/0ed94p74/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var div_clone = null;
  div_clone = $('.template').clone();
  $('.button-add').click(function() {
    //we select the box clone it and insert it after the box
    var _elm = div_clone.clone();
    _elm.find('.box-title').html('Other Address');
    _elm.find("input[type='text']").val("");
    _elm.find('.remove_btn').show();
    _elm.appendTo('#clone_here');
  })

  $(document).on("click", ".remove_btn", function(e) {
    var $e = $(e.currentTarget);
    $e.closest('.template').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="button-add" type="button" value="Clone box">
<div class="form-group box template">
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <p>Article</p>
    <select class="form-control" name="article()">
      <option value="">Smoki Coko Kokos</option>
      <option value="8">Koka Kola</option>
      <option value="10">Cipiripi</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <p>Quantity</p>
    <input class="form-control" value="3" name="qty()" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <input style="display:none;" class="remove_btn" type="button" value="Delete box">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="clone_here">
</div>
```

Comment: I checked it but it works for me, what is the problem ?

Comment: *but not functioning as required* Please specify what is not working and what is the expected behavior

Comment: thanx Rajesh ... I was missing <Script> Block now its ok, Thanx